# Redirect /blog/article to /articles/article in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

As the title says, I want to redirect from my old blog URL to the new one. Here is what I tried:

```
RewriteRule ^/blog/(.*)$ /articles/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

I really thought that this would work but it turns out that I am missing something. If you could help out that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL-path that is matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* in a per-directory context (ie. in `.htaccess`) never starts with a slash because the directory-prefix (that ends with a slash) is first removed. In order words, the regex `^/blog/(.*)$` will never match.

You would need something like the following instead:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*) /articles/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Note the absence of the slash at the start of the *pattern*. This contrasts when mod_rewrite is used in a *server* (or *virtualhost*) context, then the slash prefix is required.